# Socket.io connection from ReactJS is not being redirected by nginx as any other

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, strapi

I have a React web App which uses `axios` to communicate with the backend API. Backend receives all requests from suffix `/api` address. And after that, those are redirected by nginx to `localhost:1337` where my backend listens to requests. Everything works okay but the socket connection. The console says it can not find `domain/socket.io/...` but it should be `domain/api/socket.io/...`. My connection in the client code:

```js
const ENDPOINT = "https://sinavhukuk.com/api";
const socket = io(ENDPOINT);
```

Would mention that [Strapi](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/nginx-proxy.html) is used as a backend service (NodeJS).
Here is `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file configuration.

```js
server {
    # Listen HTTP
    listen 80;
    server_name sinavhukuk.com www.sinavhukuk.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # Listen HTTPS
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sinavhukuk.com www.sinavhukuk.com;

    # SSL config
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sinavhukuk.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sinavhukuk.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    # Static Root
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
    # Strapi API and Admin
    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }
}
```

It is responsible for redirecting `/api/...`s to `localhost:1337`. But on socket it is not completely redirected. The error I get is:

```
https://sinavhukuk.com/socket.io/..... is not found
```

As I said, if the nginx worked here as always, it should be

```
https://sinavhukuk.com/api/socket.io/.....
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Added redirection from `/socket.io/` to `/api/socket.io/` manually, but still redirection happens to `/socket.io/` instead of `/api/socket.io/`

```
# Socket.io
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api/socket.io/;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you stripping the `/api` URI prefix from the request URI with the `rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;` directive then? BTW, `rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;` is somewhat more optimal in the performance terms.

Comment: @IvanShatsky thank you for asking. These are configurations, which I followed from Strapi's official "Nginx Proxying" blog bost. The configuration is called: Sub-Folder Split

Comment: With that rewrite rule you strip the`/api` prefix from the request URI getting `https://sinavhukuk.com/socket.io/...`. If you remove it, you'd get `https://sinavhukuk.com/api/socket.io/...`.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, I just tried to get rid of the whole `rewrite` command line (if you meant so) and it broke all other attempts, neither socket page became better.  The error of 404 still occurs, as I explained in the problem description. Thanks though.